# How to pass a method from expressjs to Jade

Tags: object, pug

```
<b>ExpressJS Code

<code>
var express = require('express'),
    YUI = require('yui3').YUI,
    sys = require('sys'),
    util = require('util');

var app = module.exports = express.createServer();

app.get('/weather', function(req, res) {
    res.render('weather', {
      title: 'Weather',
      YUI: YUI
    });

</code>

At Jade Side

<code>
h1 test apge
   script(type="text/javascript")
      !=YUI  <<< this returns as text, but i want to access that object YUI
</code> 
How can I pass javascript objects from expressJS to Jade.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass JSON objects into the jade template, and then parse the JSON using JavaScript.

E.g.

```
var JSON = {
 f : function(){alert("Hello")}
}
```

You could then call JSON.f